# Can I use a mobile passcode login exclusively?

Tags: multi-factor

I get absolutely no cell coverage in the building I'm working in, nor do I have access to wifi, so any time I need to use 2-factor authentication, I cannot receive the push request.

I've been using the "passcode" feature to log in as an offline alternative, but I was curious if this method will work forever. Does it ever "run out" of codes? Are there any steps I need to take in order to continually use this method?

Comment: do you mean the rotating 6 digit code that refreshes every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

The rotating 6-digit code that is generated by the app on your phone does not run out. The number is based on a formula that uses a secret number (specific to the one account and known only to your app and the service that validates the code) and the time. So, as long as time keeps ticking, new codes will be generated.

I use old phones as 2FA code generators. They happily keep creating new codes every 30 seconds for years.

There is one weakness of the time-based system: if the clock on your phone gets out of sync with the clock on the service you are trying to log into. If your phone has no access to the cell network for a long time, there is a chance that the clock will slowly get out of sync. Then, eventually, the code that is generated won't match what the service expects.

So, steps to take? Make sure your phone can connect to the cell network every couple of months or so (or 6 or yearly). Phone clocks don't drift as badly as the clock on your microwave, but they will eventually drift.